# Get list of files Using Google Drive API

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-apis-explorer

I am able to download the file from google drive

```
var www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileName + "?alt=media&key=" + key);
```

But I having problem get list of files on my google drive.

APIs Explorer

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

Result >

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "incompleteSearch": false,
 "files": [
  {

   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1MhbG1I9Azsv2uwKj-hpjO2dTw7lxveG9",
   "name": "testassetbundle",
   "mimeType": "application/octet-stream"
  }
 ]
}
```

When I am running same request

```
var www = UnityWebRequest.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?key=" + myKey);
```

Getting

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
 }
}
```

Comment: In the second web request, the ID of the file found is not used at all. Is this a typo?

Comment: Actual request is a sample from https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/ and it works there. If you asking about unit code the result is stored in www class as json.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out, why it was not working. Download of the file is working with just a secure key. But to get list of files you need to use "OAuth 2.0"